# Partial limits, question clarification.

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't understand a question and I need clarification as to what is being asked. The question is:

Assume that $\forall n, \frac{n}{n+1}$ is a partial limit of the sequence  $\left\{{a_n}\right\}^\infty _{n=1}$, and that there is no partial limit bigger than 1, prove that there exists a subsequence  $\left\{{a_{n_k}}\right\}^\infty _{n=1}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n_k}=1$.

Are they saying that any $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is a partial limit of the sequence (1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5,...)? Because it doesn't seem to make sense to me, how do I understand and solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

We can rephrase the problematic part of the question (using [the definition of partial limit](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Partial_limit)) as follows:

> For any $n$ there exist a subsequence of $(a_n)$ which converges to $\frac{n}{n+1}$.

It is always nice to have some examples in mind. Here, $(a_n)$ could be arbitrary enumeration of rationals between half and one.

Try to solve it now :). If you still struggle, here is a sketch of a proof:

> For any $n$ you can pick (from the corresponding subsequence of $(a_n)$) an element which is arbitrarily close to $\frac{n}{n+1}$.

> So for $n=1$ there will be some $a_{k_1}$ which will be no further than, say $2^{-1}$ from $\frac{1}{2}$. For $n=2$ there will be some $a_{k_2}$ no further than $2^{-2}$ from $\frac{2}{3}$. For $n=3$ there will be some $a_{k_3}$ no further than $2^{-3}$ from $\frac{3}{4}$. And so on. Subsequence $(a_{k_n})_n$ converges to $1$.